# INSERT INTO is not "auto incrementing" the id column for me

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with an id column, an email column, and a password column.  The id column is set to primary key and auto increment as shown here:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0CK0.png)

Using MySQL workbench, I'm sending

> INSERT INTO users VALUES ('a', 'b')

but it says that the "column count doesnt match the value count at row 1" which to me means that it's expecting 3 values and not 2.  But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935252/handling-identity-columns-in-an-insert-into-table-values-statement) post, I should be able to just use two values as the id column will auto increment itself.

Clearly I am wrong about something because this is not working.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Always* include the column list when using `insert` (unless you really know what you are doing):

```
INSERT INTO users(email, password)
    VALUES ('a', 'b');
```

The id column will be auto incremented, if it is set to auto increment.

Comment: That fixed it.  I've actually never seen that done before.  thanks, I'l accept when i can